# Get the highest category while performing other type of aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

**Story:**

I am trying to get the sum of records and the max date by country and games and another column that would rank the top countries based on the sum of records:

```
select id, country, game, sum(records) as records, max(date) as max_date
from table
group by id, country, game
```

It is the country rank column that is giving me trouble. Here's what I tried:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, country ORDER BY SUM(records) DESC) as rn
```

All it does is rank the each row partition by country which is what I expected.

**Objective**

Is there a way to achieve what i want in one or two subqueries?

Here's a desired output

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------+------------+------+
| id | country |     game     | records |  max_date  | rank |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+------------+------+
|  2 | usa     | wow          |      10 | 2019-01-01 |    1 |
|  2 | usa     | wakfu        |      15 | 2019-01-01 |    1 |
|  2 | usa     | clash royale |      30 | 2019-01-01 |    1 |
|  2 | germany | dofus        |       9 | 2019-01-01 |    2 |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+------------+------+
```

Here for ID #2, country USA is 1st due to its combined sum of records from all games.

**To the request of comments below:**

Raw data looks like that:

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--+
| id | country |     game     | records |  max_date  |  |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--+
|  2 | usa     | wow          |       2 | 2018-12-01 |  |
|  2 | usa     | wow          |       5 | 2018-12-05 |  |
|  2 | usa     | wow          |       1 | 2018-12-10 |  |
|  2 | usa     | wow          |       2 | 2019-01-01 |  |
|  2 | usa     | wakfu        |      10 | 2018-12-10 |  |
|  2 | usa     | wakfu        |       5 | 2019-01-01 |  |
|  2 | usa     | clash royale |      30 | 2019-01-01 |  |
|  2 | germany | dofus        |       2 | 2018-05-01 |  |
|  2 | germany | dofus        |       4 | 2018-07-01 |  |
|  2 | germany | dofus        |       3 | 2019-01-01 |  |
+----+---------+--------------+---------+------------+--+
```

Comment: We can't help you get to your expect results if you don't show us what your data looks like *before* hand.

Comment: There is certainly a way to do this. But ROW_NUMBER is not going to be the answer. What is the answer? Not really what the question is without a [mcve]. But once you post that an answer will generally materialize pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build on your aggregation query.  This version produces a ranking that is like `row_number()`, so ties would get different values:

```
select id, country, game, records, max_date,
       dense_rank() over (order by country_sum desc, country) as ranking
from (select id, country, game, sum(records) as records, max(date) as max_date,
             sum(sum(records)) over (partition by country) as country_sum
      from mytable
      group by id, country, game
     ) cg;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=354b409d7e4e123dea962cf54064cf5b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: dense_rank will cause two countries that have the same sum to have the same rank. basically whichever one will do.  Would a top 1 in  an inner select statement work?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . That is why `country` is the second key in the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions only:

```
select 
    id, 
    country,
    game,
    game_records records,
    date max_date,
    dense_rank() over(order by country_records desc) rnk
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by id, country, game order by date desc) rn,
        sum(records) over(partition by id, country, game) as game_records,
        sum(records) over(partition by country) country_records
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
order by rnk, records
```

Thie inner query ranks records having the same `(id, country, game)` by descending `date`, and computes window sums for the same  `(id, country, game)` partition *and* for the partition made of all country records.

Then, the outer query filters on the top record in each of the first patition (this gives us the maximum date), and ranks by total records per country.

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92494ae49afedbac60442311f19297f4)** with your sample data returns:

```
id | country | game         | records | max_date            | rnk
-: | :------ | :----------- | ------: | :------------------ | :--
 2 | usa     | wow          |      10 | 01/01/2019 00:00:00 | 1  
 2 | usa     | wakfu        |      15 | 01/01/2019 00:00:00 | 1  
 2 | usa     | clash royale |      30 | 01/01/2019 00:00:00 | 1  
 2 | germany | dofus        |       9 | 01/01/2019 00:00:00 | 2
```

Comment: just ran the query with my raw data and unfortunately, the dense rank doesnt work because it can create duplicates. two different countries  can have the same sum and the rank will be the same. so my goal is to take whichever one from those that are ranked 1. Would a top 1 in  an inner select statement work?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg: just `dense_rank() over(order by country_records desc, country)`